# Namespace same method two places/"namespace endpoints"

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance, design-patterns

i'm making a facade project / wrapper to a logging library. This wrapper is to be used in multiple projects, both existing and new ones.

The namespace is gonna be like `Logger.System.Fatal`, but since the existing projects used to consume another wrapper project, they used `Logger.Fatal`.

So with the new one, I want the same method to be able to be called from both places in the namespace.

But how do i go about doing this?

I would like to be able to have the same description in both places, but have the `Logger.Fatal` give a deprecated/obsolete warning.

I have thought of doing it like this:

```
public class Logger : LogHelper.System
{
    [Obsolete("Logger.Trace is deprecated, use Logger.System.Fatal instead.")]
    public static new void Fatal(string message)
    {
        //somehow call the method that we are inheriting from
    }
    public class System : LogHelper.System
    {
        public static new void Fatal(string message)
        {
            //somehow call the method that we are inheriting from
        }
    }
}

public class LogHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Logs a message with the importance of Fatal
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">The message to log</param>
    public virtual void Fatal(string message)
    {
        //log the message
        logger.Fatal(message);
    }
}
```

But im unsure if this is the proper way to design it, or if it should just be called as normal methods referencing another?
I'm looking for some best practice advice on how to design it :)

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe this question should be asked on [Software Engineering](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) ?

Comment: _"able to have the same description in both places"_ - I'm not quiet sure what you mean with that. Could you eloberate a bit more accurate? Otherwise, fine question imo.

Comment: Is that heading towards what you wan't @Djensen? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/aa664765(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @Mafii, i meant to say summary. the description/summary you make above the method with "///", in order to fill out the descriptions in the intellisense. I would like to, if possible, to only have this summary in one place. To keep code redundancy low.

Comment: @Mafii, the using alias directives would help to expose the method in two places, but i dont see how i can put the [obsolete("string")] above some of the methods, if use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make two `Logger` classes, one in the "new" namespace, with all the implementation.
Another in the old namespace, inheriting from the new one, with an `Obsolete` attribute.

In this way, you have the implementation in the right place, no code in the old namespace, and an obsolete warning for everyone targeting the old place.

```
namespace Old
{
    [Obsolete("Use New.NewLogger instead")]
    public class OldLogger : New.NewLogger
    {
    }
}

namespace New
{
    public class NewLogger
    {
        // All your implementation here.
    }
}
```

If you need some transformation (the Old and New implementations differ in some way) you can leverage inheritance to do that.

Comment: Did you read op's comments? _" I would like to, if possible, to only have this summary in one place. To keep code redundancy low."_
Thats not what op wanted.

Comment: You don't need comments for methods you are just inheriting. The summary for the class MUST be different: one is obsolete, the other is not. AFAICT, this is exactly what the OP wants...